# Is there an OPENSSL api which can parse the certificate and tell if it is a client certificate or server certificate?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a requirement where in I have a certificate and i need to tell if it is a client certificate or a server certificate. Is there an open ssl api which tells the same.
For example a similar use case, if we want to tell if a certificate is a CA the we can use the function

***static int check_ca(const X509 *x)*** found in OpenSSL

Answer (score 2):

In theory a certificate can be use for both client and server authentication depending if it was used when initiating or receiving a SSL/TLS handshake

However you can refine this behavior by setting the *Extended Key Usage* field of the certificate.
You can see this field when executing the command `openssl x509 -in cert -text -noout` and you might get something like

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment, Key Agreement
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
```

This field is configured with the openssl configuration file (located in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`).

More information with man page: `man x509v3_config`

Comment: That sorted life for me

Answer (score 0):

> I have a requirement where in I have a certificate and i need to tell if it is a client certificate or a server certificate....

There are two types of certificates in most PKIs. They are end-entity certificates (like those used by clients and servers) and CA and Subordinate CA certificates. End-entity certificates ***lack*** ***`CA=true`*** basic constraint. CA and subordinate certificates have ***`CA=true`*** constraint and they certify the end entity certificates. Also see Apache's [Glossary of PKI Terms](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Apache-WebDAV-LDAP-HOWTO/glossary.html).

There are some key usage bits that may help you determine what the key was certified to do. However, they key usage bits are woefully inadequate and don't even cover the highest level use cases (like [server authentication versus proxying/interception](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/pkix/current/msg33425.html)).

There are extensions that can further specify what a key can be used for, but they are specific to a PKI. For example, Microsoft uses an extension to identify a user in an end-entity/user certificate. For a good discussion, see Thomas Porin's answer at [How to encode a username in PKIX certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/62746)

---

> Is there an OPENSSL api which can parse the certificate and tell if it is a client certificate or server certificate?

No, because they are both end-entity certificates. Whether its a person or server using it is inconsequential. You *can* mark a certificate with the information using an extension, but then you would need to add the additional application layer logic to recognize it.